# how to solve $y(x+y+1)dx+(x+2y)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using an integrating factor if necessary, solve the following problems $y(x+y+1)dx+(x+2y)dy=0$.plz show the detail.use integrating factor

Comment: You can find a description of how to find an integrating factor for this problem here: http://www2.fiu.edu/~aladrog/SpecialIntegratingFactors.pdf It is fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

$$y(x+y+1)dx+(x+2y)dy=0$$
Using an integrating factor is not necessary to solve this ODE.

Of course using an integrating factor is a possible method (I let you try it : John Wayland Bales's comment). But is isn't the only method, as shown below.

Change of function : $\quad Y=x+2y \quad\to\quad y=\frac{1}{2}(Y-x) \quad\to\quad dy=\frac{1}{2}(dY-dx)$
$$\frac{1}{2}(Y-x)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}(Y-x)+1\right)dx+Y\frac{1}{2}(dY-dx)=0$$
After simplification :
$$\left(Y^2-x^2-2x\right)dx+2YdY=0$$
$z=Y^2 \quad\to\quad \left(z-x^2-2x\right)dx+dz=0$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}+z=x^2+2x$$
This linear ODE is easy to solve.
$$z=x^2+c\:e^{-x}$$
$Y=\pm\sqrt{x^2+c\:e^{-x}}$
$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left( \pm\sqrt{x^2+c\:e^{-x}}-x\right)$$

Comment: are u sure it is the right answer?

Comment: Why not ? What makes you doubt ?